# Dúvida em dicionário - Python

Tags: python, dicionário

Bom dia! Estou tentando criar um dicionário onde o mesmo possui algumas chaves dentro de outras chaves, e cada chave contém mais de um item. Já procurei em vários lugares mas não encontro nada a respeito. Talvez eu não esteja fazendo uma busca correta. Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeceria muito.

Estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
    g = {"V": {"S", "X", "Y"},
         "T": {"a", "b"},
         "P": {"S": "aXa, bXb, ø", "X": "a, b, Y", "Y": "ø"},
         "S": {"S"}
         }
```

Dessa forma, a chave "P" contém várias outras chaves, que são "S", "X" e "Y". Porém dessa forma, os itens dentro dessas chaves estão sendo únicos, armazenados em um único índice. Como: "aXa, bXb, ø" estão dentro de um mesmo índice. Quero dividí-los para que cada item esteja em uma única posição.
Não sei se fui muito claro, mas se algúem tiver uma ideia, seria de muita ajuda.

Comment: "*Não sei se fui muito claro*", não foi. Você literalmente escreveu no código, `"S": "aXa, bXb, ø"`, que todos esses valores são a mesma *string* e, portanto, compõe o mesmo valor. Qual era o resultado esperado dessa operação?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Comment: Olá, Woss. Sim, eu coloquei só o código porque é para um trabalho da faculdade de Linguagens Formais e Autômatos. Estou desenvolvendo um código para simplificação de gramática livre de contexto. E nesse caso, eu preciso conseguir ler item por item dentro de cada chave. Da forma que coloquei sei que os valores estão numa mesma string, o que eu preciso é que fiquem cada valor em uma string para poder manipular esses dados. Colocar vários valores dentro de uma mesma chave em um dicionário, isso que não tô conseguindo. Já tentei colocar cada valor dentro de uma aspas mas não funciona.